# Local method variable already set

Tags: python

I cannot figure out why the local variable `lst` is `[1]` when called the second time where no arguments are passed to the `__init__` method. I expected it to be overridden by the default value, `[]`.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
    
class A():
    def __init__(self, elem=None, lst=[]):
        if elem:
            lst.append(elem)
        print(lst)


A(1)
A()
```

The output is

```
3.8.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar  5 2020, 17:29:01) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[1]
[1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) is very helpful links for this

In short, **Python’s default arguments are evaluated *once* when the function is defined**

Comment: Said differently: never use a mutable object as a default parameter - a tuple is fine but a list is not.